# tkinter canvas and threads - python 2.7.8

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I am trying to create an animation. The major libraries I use are Tkinter and Threads.

```
Function1{
    while 1{
          #code
    }
}

function2{
 #one button element
 #if button element is clicked 
 # create a thread object to invoke the Function 1
}
```

I am facing a problem that while running the program, sometimes it shows interface and then gets stucks and sometimes it just runs smoothly.

I also have a stop button to exit thread. In that I am setting a variable value to 1 such that when this variable is checked for value change in the thread the while loop get breaked. Is that the best way to exit a thread??

Comment: I suspect there is a problem in your code. Please show it to us.

Comment: @Kevin: code here http://wikisend.com/download/703338/cn_2.py

Answer (score 0):

tkinter isn't thread safe. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25431690/7432) for an example of doing simple animation without threads.