# Network growth animation

Tags: python, tkinter, networkx

I am writing a python program using the [Networkx Viewer](https://github.com/jsexauer/networkx_viewer) library. The goal of the program is to plot a graph (i.e., a set of nodes connected by vertices), and have this graph `grow' over time (i.e., new nodes emerge over time). I have written the following piece of code, based on a similar working example I took from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25430786/moving-balls-in-tkinter-canvas/25431690#25431690).

I've been trying to figure this out for the last 24 hours and am still unable to get it to work. The issue seems to be with the **after** method. If I remove the corresponding line, the program spits out a canvas display; otherwise, it doesn't display anything. Does anyone know how I can get this to work?

```
import tkinter as tk
import networkx as nx
from networkx_viewer import GraphCanvas


class GraphGrower(tk.Tk):
def __init__(self, graph):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self)
    self.graph_item = graph
    self.canvas = GraphCanvas(self.graph_item)
    self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NESW')

def add_node_after(self,node_num):
    self.graph_item.add_node(node_num)
    self.canvas = GraphCanvas(self.graph_item)
    self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NESW')
    self.canvas.after(10000, self.add_node_after(str(int(node_num)+1))) 
# REMOVE THE ABOVE LINE AND IT UPDATES THE GRAPH TO A 5 VERTEX GRAPH


# Graphs can be found at
# https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generators.html
G = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(4,0.85)

app = GraphGrower(G)
app.add_node_after(str(5))

app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using after incorrectly. Consider this line of code:

```
self.canvas.after(10000, self.add_node_after(str(int(node_num)+1)))
```

It is exactly the same as this:

```
result = self.add_node_after(str(int(node_num)+1))
self.canvas.after(10000, result)
```

See the problem? `after` requires a *callable* -- a reference to the function. If you need to pass parameters, you can add the parameters as arguments to `after`:

```
node = str(int(node_num)+1)
self.canvas.after(10000, self.add_node_after, node)
```