# tkinter python heart rate and animation

Tags: python, animation, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I am trying to make an animation that uses heart rate date as the trigger using raspberry pi.
I have used github code https://github.com/tutRPi/Raspberry-Pi-Heartbeat-Pulse-Sensor and am using the `example.py` as a basis for my work.

I have also used a great tutorial that makes balls move around the screen using tkinter which works.

I am totally new to python and am having trouble getting the animation to play on the if statement. Ideally I want the balls to move at speed generated by the bmp data, so that faster heart rates will make them move around faster. I seem to be very far from this at the moment.
If anyone can help to get this working I will be forever grateful. as it stands, the balls appear but do not move. I think there is a conflict with the movement and the bpm updating...

Here is the code:

```
from pulsesensor import Pulsesensor
import time
from tkinter import *
import random

tk = Tk()
WIDTH=1500
HEIGHT=800
canvas = Canvas(tk, bg="brown4", height=HEIGHT, width= WIDTH)
tk.title("drawing")
canvas.pack()

##below is the class to create multiple balls that are coloured
##and move and detect the edge and bounce

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, color, size):
        self.shape  = canvas.create_oval (10, 10, size,  size, fill=color, 
                                          outline=color, stipple="gray25")
        self.xspeed = random.randrange(-1,5)
        self.yspeed = random.randrange(-1,5)

    def move(self):
        canvas.move(self.shape, self.xspeed, self.yspeed)
        pos = canvas.coords(self.shape)
        if pos[3]>=HEIGHT or pos[1]<=0:
            self.yspeed=-self.yspeed
        if pos[2] >=WIDTH or pos[0] <=0:
            self.xspeed=-self.xspeed


colors=["red4", "red3", "OrangeRed2","OrangeRed4","firebrick3"]
##this is make 100 balls
balls=[]
##this is to set the colour and size of the balls which is randomised:
for i in range (100):
    balls.append(Ball(random.choice(colors), random.randrange(150, 200)))

##this is to call the balls
##while True:

p = Pulsesensor()
p.startAsyncBPM()

try:
    while True:
        bpm = p.BPM
        if bpm > 0:
            print("BPM: %d" % bpm)
            for ball in balls:
                    ball.move()
            tk.update()
            time.sleep(0.02)
            tk.mainloop()
        else:
            print("No Heartbeat found")
        time.sleep(1)
except:
    p.stopAsyncBPM()
```

Comment: Where are you changing the speed of the balls? It doesn't seem to be anywhere.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the reply. I am not changing the speed as yet. That is the end goal, but I think I am doing something wrong in calling the class?

Comment: You picked a bad tutorial for how to do animation. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25431690/7432

Comment: thank you Bryan, I am trying to figure it out now

Comment: Sadly I failed to understand what is different from what I have apart from the way in which you are calling the functions. This did not work as follows try:
    while True:
        bpm = p.BPM
        if bpm > 0: ball.move()
         
            root.mainloop()
        else:
            print("No Heartbeat found")
        time.sleep(1)

Comment: For one, you must call `mainloop` exactly once. You're calling it in a loop, which almost certainly isn't doing what you think it's doing. For another, you're calling `sleep` which you should never do in the main thread of a GUI.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a Raspberry-Pi or a Pulse Sensor, so the following could only be tested to a certain degree—but hopefully it will provide you better foundation code. I reduced the number of balls to make it easier to see what's going on. I don't really understand how their movement is supposed to relate to pulse-rate, so you'll need to flesh that out yourself...

When using tkinter it's important to understand that everything that happens must do so via the `mainloop()` which generally doesn't return until the application script exits (so it's essentially an endless loop). This means you generally can't just call it whenever you want. In this case, a "polling" function is used and it is called at set intervals to update the `Canvas` object—which will all happens *while* the `mainloop()` is running.

```
from pulsesensor import Pulsesensor
import random
from tkinter import *

WIDTH=1500
HEIGHT=800
COLORS = ["red4", "red3", "OrangeRed2", "OrangeRed4", "firebrick3"]
DELAY = 200  # In millisecs
NUMBALLS = 5

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, color, size):
        self.shape = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, size,  size, fill=color,
                                        outline=color, stipple="gray25")
        self.xspeed = random.randrange(-1, 5)
        self.yspeed = random.randrange(-1, 5)

    def move(self):
        canvas.move(self.shape, self.xspeed, self.yspeed)
        pos = canvas.coords(self.shape)
        if pos[3] >= HEIGHT or pos[1] <= 0:
            self.yspeed = -self.yspeed
        if pos[2] >= WIDTH or pos[0] <= 0:
            self.xspeed = -self.xspeed

def poll(p):
    try:
#        bpm = p.BPM
        bpm = random.randint(0, 200)  # Random value for testing.
        if bpm < 1:
#            print("No Heartbeat found")
            pass
        else:
#            print("BPM: %d" % bpm)
            for ball in balls:
                ball.move()
    except Exception as exc:
        print('Exception raised: {}'.format(exc))
        p.stopAsyncBPM()
        root.quit()

    root.after(DELAY, poll, p)  # Call this function again after delay.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Beating Heart")
    canvas = Canvas(root, bg="brown4", height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
    canvas.pack()
    balls = [Ball(random.choice(COLORS), random.randrange(150, 200))
                for _ in range(NUMBALLS)]

    p = Pulsesensor()
    p.startAsyncBPM()
    poll(p)  # Start polling.
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the call to `update_idletasks` inside of `poll`. The update happens automatically between `poll` returning and running again.

Comment: @Bryan: Removed. Wasn't sure if it was really needed, so put it in just in case. Once again, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Thank yo u both for your help. I will let you know once I have finished it and hopefully share the results! All the best

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I have another question, but cannot seem to paste the code here so I will try and start a new thread. thanks again.