# Create an image in a canvas inside a class

Tags: python, image, oop, tkinter, canvas

I wanted to create a chess program using OOP. So I made a superclass `Pieces`, a subclass `Bishop`, and a UI class `GameUI`. I created a canvas in the class GameUI. I wanted, that when I instantiate an object bishop in the class `GameUI`, it shows an Image from a bishop, on the canvas.

The problem is, when I instantiate the `Bishop`, I don't see any image. So I tried to do the same with a text : instead of using the method create_image from the class `Canvas`, I used the method create_text, and it worked : I saw a text on the canvas. That means, the problem comes from the method `create_image`, and I don't understand it.

If I create an Image directly in the class `GameUi`, it works! but that's not what I want...

So I don't have any error message. I see the canvas (with a blue background), but no image on it.

Here's the code :

```
from tkinter import PhotoImage, Tk, Canvas


class Pieces:

    def __init__(self, can, color, x_position, y_position):
        self.color = color
        self.x_position = x_position
        self.y_position = y_position


class Bishop(Pieces):

    def __init__(self, can, color, x_position, y_position):

        super().__init__(can, color, x_position, y_position)

        if color == "black":
            icon_path = 'black_bishop.png'
        elif color == "white":
            icon_path = 'white_bishop.png'

        icon = PhotoImage(file=icon_path)  # doesn't see the image
        can.create_image(x, y, image=icon)


class GameUI:

    def __init__(self):

        self.windows = Tk()
        self.windows.title("My chess game")
        self.windows.geometry("1080x720")
        self.windows.minsize(300, 420)

        self.can = Canvas(self.windows, width=1000, height=600, bg='skyblue')
        
        icon = PhotoImage(file=icon_path)  # here I create the image in this class, and
        can.create_image(x, y, image=icon)  # we can see it very well

        self.bishop = Bishop(self.can, "black", 50, 50)
        self.can.pack()
        self.windows.mainloop()


app = GameUI()
```

Comment: Try using `self.icon`

Comment: Code in `GameUI.__init__` isn't equal to code in `Bishop.__init__`. Compare results using implicit values in GameUI.__init__: `file='black_bishop.png'`, `x=50`, `y=50`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your code work, I decided to sort of rewrite it based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25431690/14280450). It works now, but really the only thing that you needed to add was `self.icon` instead of `icon`. `icon` gets garbage collected since there is no further reference to it, while `self.icon` remains. Also, it's not entirely the same as yours was, so it probably needs a bit of rewriting too.

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint

class Piece:
    def __init__(self, canvas, x1, y1):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.y1 = y1
        self.canvas = canvas

class Bishop(Piece):
    def __init__(self, canvas, x1, y1, color):
        super().__init__(canvas, x1, y1)

        if color == "black":
            icon_path = 'black_bishop.png'
        elif color == "white":
            icon_path = 'white_bishop.png'

        self.icon = PhotoImage(file=icon_path)
        self.ball = canvas.create_image(self.x1, self.y1, image=self.icon)

    def move_piece(self):
        deltax = randint(0,5)
        deltay = randint(0,5)
        self.canvas.move(self.ball, deltax, deltay)
        self.canvas.after(50, self.move_piece)

class GameUI:
    def __init__(self):
        # initialize root Window and canvas
        root = Tk()
        root.title("Chess")
        root.resizable(False,False)
        canvas = Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300)
        canvas.pack()

        # create two ball objects and animate them
        bishop1 = Bishop(canvas, 10, 10, 'white')
        bishop2 = Bishop(canvas, 60, 60, 'black')

        bishop1.move_piece()
        bishop2.move_piece()

        root.mainloop()

app = GameUI()
```